# jQuery click to pop game

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I Find myself dazed and confused, I need to create a jquery mini game, where the goal is to pop a balloon in the least amount of time possible, but the balloon should give some resistance so that you have to click at least 20 times for it to pop..

So basically... There will be a balloon and then you have to try and get 20 clicks in the shortest amount of time possible for it to pop so that your time will be added to a score board... And also there needs to be a progress bar displaying progress...

I am very much a beginner in all this.. any advice? or resources i can look at just to get a small idea of how?

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Have you any experience with HTML, CSS, or jQuery at all?  If not, then you've a long way to go unfortunately.  Don't let that put you off however.

Comment: I do have experience in all of these... its more the code.. I just don't know how to grasp all of this into code... Funny because I have done alot of projects.. but this one i am completely blank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the fiddle it may helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7p6m/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var click1=0;
 var random_no=0;
 function ran(){
 random_no=Math.round(Math.random()*10)+20;
          }
 ran();
 $("#balloon").click(function(){
 click1++;
 if(click1==random_no)
    {
    $("#balloon").css("background-image", "url(http://s11.postimg.org/g1349h43n/images.jpg)");
    }
 });
 });
```

the balloon was poped at random count between 20 to 30

Comment: Thank you so much.. its a good start I will look into it immediately

Comment: All the best. Dawid van der Hoven